# How to Get Iterations to Update with addition to list

Tags: python, list, tkinter, iteration

So I've been struggling with an issue for a week or so, been googling around trying to find different solutions, etc and getting nowhere. I was advised to put functioning code on here so I've cut it down some while still showing the issue.

I want to have a main page listing a set of goals, then if you click on the "Goal Entry" button up top a new window opens where you can input additional goals. Then you type in your desired additions, hit enter, and it adds it to the list on the main page.

I've accomplished all of the above EXCEPT, after you add the goals (and I have the list printing before and after so I know they're being added) and the entry window closes, the list of labels (created by an iteration) hasn't updated accordingly.

How do I get the list on the main page to automatically update when a new item is added to the list?

```
from tkinter import *

pg = ["goal1","goal2"]
pgtotal=1
psum=len(pg)


class yeargoals():
global pg, hg, fg, rg, rgtotal
def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    master.title("This Year's Goals")

    self.buttonframe = Frame(root)
    self.buttonframe.pack(side=TOP, padx = 150, fill=BOTH)
    self.home = Button(self.buttonframe, text="Home Page")
    self.home.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10)
    self.enter = Button(self.buttonframe, text="Goal Entry", command=self.winenter)
    self.enter.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10)
    self.finalize = Button(self.buttonframe, text="Finalize for Year")
    self.finalize.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10)
    self.dashboard = Button(self.buttonframe, text="Goal Dashboard")
    self.dashboard.grid(row=1,column=4, padx=10)

    self.goalframe = Frame(root)
    self.goalframe.pack(side=TOP, padx=150, pady=50, fill=BOTH, expand = True)

    #Makes the label Fram I want the Checkboxes to go in
    self.LabelFramep= LabelFrame(self.goalframe,text="Professional Goals")
    self.LabelFramep.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, anchor = N, fill=BOTH, expand = True)

    #Makes the  from the list above
    for goal in pg:
        l = Checkbutton(self.LabelFramep, text=goal, variable=Variable())
        l.config(font=("Courier",12))
        l.grid(sticky=W)

    self.ptotal=Label(self.LabelFramep,text="Progress so far: "+str(pgtotal)+"/"+str(psum))
    self.ptotal.config(font=("Courier",12))
    self.ptotal.grid(sticky=W)
    self.pper=Label(self.LabelFramep, text=str(round((pgtotal/psum)*100))+"% Complete")
    self.pper.config(font=("Courier",12))
    self.pper.grid(sticky=W)


def winenter(self):
    global pg
    self.winenter = Toplevel(root)
    options = ["Professional", "Health", "Financial", "Reward Items"]
    variable = StringVar(self.winenter)
    variable.set(options[0])
#Title of entry section
    t1 = Label(self.winenter, text="New Goal Entry")
    t1.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
#dropdown menu
    d = OptionMenu(self.winenter, variable, *options)
    d.grid(row=1, column=2)
#entry fields
    e1 = Entry(self.winenter)
    e1.grid(row=2, column=2, padx = 10, pady=5)
    e2 = Entry(self.winenter)
    e2.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)
    e3 = Entry(self.winenter)
    e3.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)
    e4 = Entry(self.winenter)
    e4.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)
    e5 = Entry(self.winenter)
    e5.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=10, pady=5)
#Label for entry fields
    l1 = Label(self.winenter, text="Goal Number 1")
    l1.grid(row=2, column=1)
    l2 = Label(self.winenter, text="Goal Number 2")
    l2.grid(row=3, column=1)
    l3 = Label(self.winenter, text="Goal Number 3")
    l3.grid(row=4, column=1)
    l4 = Label(self.winenter, text="Goal Number 4")
    l4.grid(row=5, column=1)
    l5 = Label(self.winenter, text="Goal Number 5")
    l5.grid(row=6, column=1)

    def enter():
        global pg, main
        print (pg)
        if variable.get() == "Professional":
            pg.append(e1.get())
        self.winenter.destroy()
        print (pg)

    #Goal entry execute button
    b = Button(self.winenter, text="Enter Goals", command=enter)
    b.grid(row=7, column = 1)

root = Tk()
Window = yeargoals(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callback function to button "Enter Goals", you have done nothing to update your main window. Maybe you think the main window will *magically* keep updated with the variable `pg`, **no**, you need to do all those updates manually in your callback function.

For example, change your callback `enter()` to:

```
def enter():
    global pg, main
    print (pg)
    if variable.get() == "Professional":
        pg.append(e1.get())
        l = Checkbutton(self.LabelFramep, text=pg[-1], variable=Variable())
        l.config(font=("Courier",12))
        l.grid(sticky=W)
    self.winenter.destroy()
    print (pg)
```

You can find the main window is updated after you click "Enter Goals".